# Disk visible system_profiler but neither diskutil nor Disk Utility can see it

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I have an external USB disk that is not responding (macOS). It was making clicking noises earlier, but now it sounds normal.

It powers up to a solid blue light, and sounds normal. *edit* It does that at first, but after awhile the light begins flashing and then I can hear clicking or thunking noises inside (blech).

I can see the disk via `system_profiler` e.g.

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType | more
USB 3.1 Bus:

  Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBXHCITR
  PCI Device ID: 0x15ec 
  PCI Revision ID: 0x0006 
  PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086 
  Bus Number: 0x01 

    Expansion Desk:

      Product ID: 0x331a
      Vendor ID: 0x0bc2  (Seagate LLC)
      Version: 9.11
      Serial Number: NA8X507J
      Speed: Up to 5 Gb/sec
      Manufacturer: Seagate
      Location ID: 0x01200000 / 7
      Current Available (mA): 900
      Current Required (mA): 8
      Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

But it's not visible via diskutil. It only shows the internal hard drive.

How do I get this to be at least visible to diskutil (or Disk Utility.app) so I can attempt a repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the system profiler doesn't see the disk at all - what it indeed does see, is the USB device that fronts it.

Think of it as a chain of devices: System -> USB Controller -> USB cable -> USB/SATA adapter -> SATA disk, with only the last link in the chain failing. Obviously the USB subsystem would see the USB device, but would be unable to assign it to a block device handle. So it will show up on the USB device tree, but not on the block device tree.

This of course implies, that you can't make it visible in any program, that accesses only block devices - that includes disk utility.

Comment: i.e. it's dead. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The disk is very probably dead. 
There is an app called DriveDx that you can download (free trial) from  https://binaryfruit.com/. Download it with the built-in kext. This app may see it and give info about the disk.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!